# how to create popup menu in android cardview

Tags: android, popupmenu

I want to create popup menu with edit and delete option on card view I have tried the below code but I am getting force close at `popup.show();`with fatal exception `onclick` of `imageview`. What should i do to create popup menu on `cardview`?

```
public class ShipRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShipRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final String PRODUCTID = "PRODUCTID";
public static final String PRODUCTNAME = "PRODUCTNAME";

List<CustDatabaseModel> dbCustList;
static Context context;
public ImageView btndots;

ShipRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<CustDatabaseModel> dbCustList ){
    this.dbCustList = new ArrayList<CustDatabaseModel>();
    this.context = context;
    this.dbCustList = dbCustList;

}

@Override
public ShipRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.address_list, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ShipRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.address.setText(dbCustList.get(position).getaddress());
    holder.city.setText(dbCustList.get(position).getcity());
    holder.state.setText(dbCustList.get(position).getstate());
    holder.zipcode.setText(dbCustList.get(position).getzip());

  final String adr=dbCustList.get(position).getaddress().toString();

    holder.btndots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, btndots);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Intent i;
                    if ((item.getTitle().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("Edit")) {
                        Toast.makeText(ShipRecyclerAdapter.context, "you have clicked Menu image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if ((item.getTitle().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("Delete")) {
                        Toast.makeText(ShipRecyclerAdapter.context, "you have clicked Menu image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show();
        }
    });



    //closing the setOnClickListener method



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbCustList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView state,address,city,zipcode;
    public ImageView btndots;



    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        address = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
        city = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCity);
        zipcode = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textViewZipcode);
        state = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textViewState);
        this.btndots = (ImageView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.cmenu);


    }



}
```

}`

Comment: Your question is not clear, You are talking about pop up menu, and showing code for adapter. Where is the code for pop menu

Comment: see this stack documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/169/recyclerview/14542/popup-menu-with-recyclerview#t=201611030914370847887

Answer (score 6):

first create xml file in menu folder like this,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:title="@string/delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

then create method in your adapter class,

```
private void showPopup(View view, final int position) {
    // pass the imageview id
    View menuItemView = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_song_list_more);
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, menuItemView);
    MenuInflater inflate = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflate.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    Log.e("position -- " + position);

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.edit:
                  // do what you need.
                    break;
                case R.id.delete:
          // do what you need .
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

> call this method of your imageview click event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in Oncreate of your activity you first register for context menu for  recyclerView    using

```
registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);
```

and create context menu like

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");//groupId, itemId, order, title
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SMS");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getTitle()=="Call"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "calling code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="SMS"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sending sms code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: getting error 'cannot resolve method' at super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);